# AWS S3 MimeMessage files generated by SES cause 403 when accessed by java SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sdk, amazon-ses

So I've been working with this problem all day, and I can't seem to find the cause of this issue.

I have an action in SES that will forward all emails at a specific subdomain to a specific bucket. These messages can be downloaded fine and contain all necessary information when interacted with in the console, but fail to be retrieved by using getObject() in the Java SDK.

I can confirm that the SDK credentials work correctly, as I can download other files from the same bucket, even with the same key prefix through my code.

That proves my bucket policy is set up correctly. The entry dealing with the getObject permission looks like this:

```
{
    "Sid": "EmailsAccess",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": "*",
    "Action": [
        "s3:DeleteObject",
        "s3:GetObject"
    ],
    "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::foo-bucket-foo/foo-prefix-foo/*"
}
```

I'm sure that the root cause of the issue has to do with the owner, since that is defined as "aws-ses+publishing.us-east-1.prod" in each file generated by SES. Why is that causing my code to bring up 403s? Is there any way to change a file's owner, or is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: The alternate owner is normal, the objects should have the ACL `bucket-owner-full-control`.  You may need more permissions to access these objects -- possibly `s3:ListBucket` on the bucket level, or `s3:GetObjectAcl` on the object level.  Speculation, as to which permission, but I'll bet that the issue is permission related -- your permissions.

Comment: I can confirm that they are missing the `bucket-owner-full-control` ACL. Is there any way to configure SES to change that, or automate changing of ACLs when the file is uploaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue being that the accounts used in the SDK were a different set of accounts from the bucket owner, and did not have permission to view those specific messages.

Following  [this guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-walkthroughs-managing-access-example4.html) would have solved the issue, but we decided to go another route and are trying to log in using the bucket owner accounts.